# How to sync Linux folder on Google drive with bash?

Tags: linux, synchronization, google-drive

I know this is a sort of entry-level question but: is there a simple way to sync a folder on Ubuntu computers (let's say Documents) with Google drive?

I tried with grive, but I get an access error on google. also, the process should be easy enough with standard bash command, is it?

What would be the procedure to sync the Document folder between computers with bash?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried something like https://www.insynchq.com/?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rclone`](https://rclone.org/)

> Rclone has powerful cloud equivalents to the unix commands rsync, cp, mv, mount, ls, ncdu, tree, rm, and cat. **Rclone's familiar syntax includes shell pipeline support**, and --dry-run protection. **It is used at the command line**, in scripts or via its API
> *(Emphasis mine)*

It works with Google Drive and [many other products](https://rclone.org/#providers).